# OpenCV - Projection, homography matrix and bird's eye view

Tags: opencv, projection, homography

I'd like to get homography matrix to Bird's eye view and I know the projection Matrix of the camera. Is there any relation between them?

Thanks.

Comment: can you formulate a little bit more?

Comment: So, I work with autonomous car and I'd like to get Homography Matrix to Bird's eye view and there are many ways to do that, but I have Projetion Matrix of the camera and I'd like, with this, get the Homography Matrix, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

A projection matrix is defined as a product of camera's intrinsic (e.g. focal length, principal points,  etc.) and extrinsic (rotation and translation) matrices. The question is w.r.t what your rotation and translation are? For example, I can imagine another camera or an object in 3D with respect to which you have these rotations and translations. Otherwise your projection is just an intrinsic matrix.

Think first about the pieces of information you need to know to obtain a bird’s eye view: you need to know at least how your camera is oriented w.r.t ground surface. If you also know camera elevation you can create a metric reconstruction. But since you mentioned a homography, I assume that you consider a bird’s eye view of a flat surface since a *homography maps the points on two flat surfaces*, in your case the points on a flat ground to the points on your flat sensor.

Let’s consider a pinhole camera equation. It basically says that 
[u, v, 1]<sup>T</sup> ~ A*[R|t][x, y, z, 1]<sup>T</sup>, where A is a camera intrinsic matrix. Now since you deal with a ground **plane**, you can align a new coordinate system with it by setting z=0; R|t are rotation and translation matrices from this coordinate system into your camera-aligned system;

Next, note that your R|t is a 3x4 matrix and it looses one dimension since z=0; it becomes 3x3 or Homography which is equal now to H=A*R’|t; Ok all we did was proving that a homography mapping existed between the ground and your sensor;

Now, you want another kind of homography that happens during pure camera rotations and zooms between points on sensor before and after rotations/zoom; that is you want to rotate the camera down and possibly zoom out. Again, think in terms of a pinhole camera equation: originally you had H1=A ( here I threw out R|T as irrelevant for now) and then you rotated your camera and you have H2=AR; in other words, H1 is how you make your image now and H2 is how you want your image look like.
The relations between two is what you want to find, H12, and it is also a homography since the Homography is a **family** of transformations (use this simple heuristics: what happens in a  family stays in the family). Since the same surface can generate images either with H1 or H2 we can assemble H12 by undoing H1 (back to the ground plane) and applying H2 (from the ground to a sensor bird’s eye view); in a way this resembles operations with vectors, you just have to respect the order of matrix application from *the right to the left*:
**H12 = H2*H1<sup>-1</sup>=A*R*A<sup>-1</sup>=P*A<sup>-1</sup>**  , where we substituted the expressions for H1, H2 and finally for a projection matrix (in case you do have it)

This is your answer, and if the rotation R is unknown it can be guessed from the camera orientation w.r.t. the ground or calculated using [solvePnP()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnp#cv2.solvePnP) from the opeCV library. Finally, when I do this on a cell phone I just use its accelerometer readings as a good approximation since when a cell phone is not accelerated the readings represent a gravity vector which gives the rotation w.r.t. flat horizontal ground.

When you plot your bird’s eye view as an image you will notice that its boundaries turned from rectangular into some kind of a trapezoid (due to a camera frustum shape) and there are some holes at the distant locations (due to the insufficient sampling rate). You can interpolate inside the holes using [wrapPerspective()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue%29)

Comment: how do I figure out the translational part? The image after warping with H12 goes out of the viewing area I need to translate it.