# How to get Bird's Eye View from KITTI by Projection Matrix?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix-transform, kitti

The goal is to get the Bird's Eye View from KITTI images (dataset), and I have the Projection Matrix (3x4).

There are many ways to generate transformation matrices. For Bird's Eye View I have read some kind math expressions, like:

H12 = H2*H1-1=A*R*A-1=P*A-1 in [OpenCV - Projection, homography matrix and bird's eye view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885906/opencv-projection-homography-matrix-and-birds-eye-view)

and x = Pi * Tr * X in [kitti dataset camera projection matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218743/kitti-dataset-camera-projection-matrix)

but none of these options worked for my purpose.

## PYTHON CODE

import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('Data/RGB/000007.png')

maxHeight, maxWidth = image.shape[:2]

## M has 3x4 dimensions

M = np.array(([721.5377, 0.0, 609.5593, 44.85728], [0.0, 721.5377, 72.854, 0.2163791], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, .002745884]))

## Here It's necessary a M matrix with 3x3 dimensions

warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

## show the original and warped images

cv2.imshow("Original", image)

cv2.imshow("Warped", warped)

cv2.waitKey(0)

I need to know how to manage the Projection Matrix for getting Bird's Eye View.

So far, everything I've tried throws warped images at me, without information even close to what I need.

[This is a example of image from the KITTI database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTP63.jpg)

[This is other example of image from the KITTI database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSSja.jpg)

On the left, images are shown detecting cars in 3D (above) and 2D (below). On the right is the Bird's Eye View that I want to obtain. Therefore, I need to obtain the transformation matrix to transform the coordinates of the boxes that delimit the cars.

Comment: can you show one of those kitti bird's eye view images? To get an idea of what you want ro achive

Comment: I have already added a couple of images in the post.

Comment: you want to get the image on the right? Just define 4 points on the ground plane of your camera images and corresponding 4 points on the bird's eye image and getPerspectiveTransform to get the conversion.

Comment: if you have the boxes in 3d coordinates, just remove the z coordinate to get an orthogonal projection. Afterwards scale and translate the space to your desired image space.

Comment: I do not want to use the 4-point method because it is miles of frames that I must process, each frame offers its own Projection Matrix values. That's why I want to use that matrix, I guess that way I will get more accurate results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code to manually build a bird's eye view transform:

```
cv::Mat1d CameraModel::getInversePerspectiveMapping(double pixelPerMeter, cv::Point const & origin) const {
    double f = pixelPerMeter * cameraPosition()[2];
    cv::Mat1d R(3,3);
    R <<  0, 1, 0,
          1, 0, 0,
          0, 0, 1;

    cv::Mat1d K(3,3);
    K << f, 0, origin.x, 
         0, f, origin.y, 
         0, 0, 1;
    cv::Mat1d transformtoGround = K * R * mCameraToCarMatrix(cv::Range(0,3), cv::Range(0,3));
    return transformtoGround * mIntrinsicMatrix.inv();
}
```

The member variables/functions used inside the functions are

- `mCameraToCarMatrix`: a 4x4 matrix holding the homogeneous rigid transformation from the camera's coordinate system to the car's coordinate system. The camera's axes are x-right, y-down, z-forward. The car's axes are x-forward, y-left, z-up. Within this function only the rotation part of `mCameraToCarMatrix` is used.
- `mIntrinsicMatrix`: the 3x3 matrix holding the camera's intrinsic parameters
- `cameraPosition()[2]`: the Z-coordinate  (height) of the camera in the car's coordinate frame. It's the same as `mCameraToCarMatrix(2,3)`.

The function parameters:

- `pixelPerMeter`: the resolution of the bird's eye view image. A distance of 1 meter on the XY plane will translate to `pixelPerMeter` pixels in the bird's eye view image.
- `origin`: the camera's position in the bird's eye view image

You can pass the transform matrix to `cv::initUndistortRectifyMaps()` as `newCameraMatrix` and then use `cv::remap` to create the bird's eye view image.

Comment: Is this code used with the images of the KITTI database?

I understand the use of the matrix R (rotation) and K (intrisic), but do you know what would be the relationship between the rest of the variables and the projection matrix offered by KITTI?

Comment: It's my source code from a different application. The projection matrix is a product of the intrinsic matrix and the extrinsic transformations from car to camera frame. Within my code I would compute P as `P = mIntrinsicMatrix * mCameraToCarMatrix.inv()(cv::Range(0,3), cv::Range(0,4));` I'm not sure if you can reverse that.

Comment: The problem is that my projection matrix is ​​3x4, I don't know what I need to get a 3x3 transformation matrix.